# не могу загрузить картинку в Tkinter: _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\Users\location\imageName.png": no such file or directory

Tags: python, tkinter

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/JURAPC/Desktop/1.py", line 24, in <module>
    filename = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\location\\imageName.png")
  File "C:\Users\JURAPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3539, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\JURAPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3495, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\Users\location\imageName.png": no such file or directory
```

вот такая ошибка

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=128, height=128)
filename = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\JURAPC\\Desktop\\домашка\\Python\\art\\102549-artwork-fantasy_art-waterfall-mountain-landscape-forest-colorful-sunlight.jpglena.jpg") # файл с графическим изображением


c.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor="nw")

c.pack()

Label(root, text=filename).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Попробуйте дополнительные слеши убрать кроме диска типо `C:\\ User\JURAPC` и т.д.

Comment: @Twiss убирать не нужно (в новых версиях ошибку получите SyntaxError на незнакомых последовательностях `\x`). Хотя проще здесь raw string literal использовать, чтобы не удваивать все слеши: `r'c:\Users\...'`

Comment: В ошибке написано про строку `filename = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\location\\imageName.png")`, у автора в примере кода другой путь: `filename = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\JURAPC\\Desktop\\домашка\\Python\\art\\102549-artwork-fantasy_art-waterfall-mountain-landscape-forest-colorful-sunlight.jpglena.jpg")`

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте на `c.create_image(0, 0, image=filename, anchor="nw")`

Comment: File "C:\Users\JURAPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3539, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\JURAPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3495, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "C:\Users\JURAPC\Desktop\домашка\Python\art\4751.jpg"              ТЕПЕРЬ ТАКАЯ ОШИБКА

Comment: Попробуйте какой-нибудь другой путь (возможно, мешает кириллица в пути).

Comment: ничего не помагло

Comment: помогите паже, люди

Comment: @A.Kross filename имя в заблуждение вводит (для объекта PhotoImage). Лучше переименуйте в img¶ Если одну ошибку вам исправили, то отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос о следующей ошибке спросите.

Answer (score 0):

Поместите Ваше изображение в одну папку с Вашим python файлом, и используйте

```py
filename = PhotoImage(file = "102549-artwork-fantasy_art-waterfall-mountain-landscape-forest-colorful-sunlight.jpglena.jpg")
fileframe = Label(s1, image=filename) # Создаём рамку для для картинки
fileframe.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Пожалуйста, отпишитесь в комментариях, если это не поможет.